# Remove resizable cursor in kQuery resizable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I have created a container which is not resizable during initialization but when I'm clicking it it's width is expanding and then it is resizable,and on clicking again it's width it again contracting and the container becomes not resizable. However the problem is I'm able to disable resizable on the container but resize cursor is still there, how can I remove it ?

I'm using this code:

```
// while intializing
$(".container").resizable({
    disabled:true,
    handles:"e,w"
});

//on Click event

disableSideBarResize: function() {
    $(".container").resizable().resizable("disable");
},

enableSideBarResize: function() {
    $(".container").resizable().resizable("enable");
},
```

But I'm not able to remove the resize cursor/icon. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

> $( ".selector" ).resizable( "disable" );

CDN Link: First, add jQuery UI scripts needed for your project.

> code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
> Blockquote
>
> code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js And code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

Check the link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-ui-resizable-disable-method/

Comment: I have tried this but when I'm toggling between enable and disable , there is element style adding display block in class ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e, because of which I can still see the resizable icon again